# Opencv C++ grayscale image black pixeled result (when replacing image values)

Tags: c++, image, opencv, pixel, grayscale

I'm new in opencv and I had this problem...

Given the following Mat type (globally declarated)
    Mat src_gray;
    Mat dst;

I have dst being a zero grayscale Mat with this initialization

```
dst=Mat::zeros(src_gray.size(), CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

It seems I can't edit the pixels on the dst image (when I use imwrite, it gives me a black image as if I hadn't done anything).
This is the code I currently have:

```
  for(int i=0;i<=dst.cols;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<=dst.rows;j++)
    {
        dst.at<uchar>(j,i)=255;
    }
  imwrite( "img_res.png", dst );
```

The result Image has the dimensions it's supposed to have, but it is a black pixeled picture, shouldn't it be a white pixeled Image?

I don't know if it is relevant if I mention that I have 3 global Mats

```
Mat image;
Mat src_gray;
Mat dst;
```

Which are initialized this way:

```
image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

cvtColor( image, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
```

Then, I release them as:

```
image.release();
dst.release();
src_gray.release();
```

The other problem I get is that when I release the Mats (during execution), I get the "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error. (I code from Linux Ubuntu distri)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
dst=Mat::zeros(src_gray.size(), CV_8UC1);
```

When you use CV_BGR2GRAY, you are creating a Mat with 3 color channels, then, it's not possible to assign a number when you have an array of numbers (B,G,R).
With CV_8UC1, you create a Mat with 1 color channel of uchar then it should works with:

```
dst.at<uchar>(j,i)=255;
```